# capistrano 3 pury ruby error -- Don't know how to build task ':check'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, capistrano, sshkit

i followed [capistrano in ruby script](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/capistrano-pure-ruby/) documentation.

my files:

```
$ ls
deploy.rb  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock
```

capistrano version:

```
$ cat Gemfile | grep -i cap
  gem "capistrano", "3.2.1"
```

ruby version:

```
$ bundle exec ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

ruby script:

```
require "capistrano/all"
set :application, "my_app"
set :deploy_to, "/home/my_app"
set :tmp_dir, "/tmp"
set :keep_releases, 5
SSHKit::Backend::Netssh.configure { |ssh| ssh.ssh_options = { forward_agent: true,  port: 22, user: "deploy_user", keys: "/ssh/key" } }
server "host.example.com", roles: [:myrole]
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
cap_gem_dir = File.join Gem::Specification.find_by_name("capistrano").gem_dir, "lib", "capistrano", "tasks", "*.rake"
Dir.glob(cap_gem_dir).each { |r| import r }
Capistrano::Application.invoke("deploy")
```

execution:

```
$ bundle exec ruby deploy.rb 
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]': Don't know how to build task ':check' (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:353:in `[]'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:15:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:15:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:15:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:64:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:64:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:15:in `invoke'
    from deploy.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

although i am not sure, it seems that the namespace is missing -- `Don't know how to build task ':check'` -- where `':check'` should be `'deploy:check'`.

**update:**

seems that `scm` variable must be set.

```
$ grep -nH scm /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:9:    invoke "#{scm}:create_release"
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:36:    invoke "#{scm}:check"
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:205:    invoke "#{scm}:set_current_revision"
```

adding `set :scm, "deploy"` let it continue, but then it fails

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]': Don't know how to build task 'deploy:create_release' (RuntimeError)
```

can you please help me understand what is the error and how it might be fixed?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the `scm` option to `:git`. So this: `set :scm, :git`. At least that is the default [Capistrano itself has](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/defaults.rb#L1).

Also, why didn't you set the `stage` option as described in [capistrano pure ruby guide](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/capistrano-pure-ruby/)?

The page explicitly says the `stage` option needs to be sed before `setup` and `deploy` files are loaded.

> Note that the require order is important as the stage needs to be set before you load setup and deploy.

Apart from that, you're doing a pretty novel work here (you're the first one I know that's doing this).

Comment: firstly, thanks for the reply. secondly, setting `scm` to `:git` does not solve the issue, see my `grep` update above. also, adding `set :stage, :production` has no effect since `Capistrano::Application.invoke("production")` is not invoked. though, i set it, it fails due to the `scm`. any other ideas? btw, you could have test your suggestion, you have whatever you need.